# Unable to pass variable from javascript to PHP and back

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm unable to get my AJAX request to work. I'm able to receive data from the php, but I'm unable to send data to it.

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#btnSubmit").click(function()    {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'checkinfo.php',
    data: { address: "37.187.139.123", port: "26618" },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function(data)
    {
    alert(data);
    }
});
});
```

PHP

```
<?php
$SERVER_IP = $_REQUEST['address'];
$SERVER_PORT = $_REQUEST['port'];
$QUERY_PORT = $_REQUEST['port'];

$HEADS = "3D";
$show_max = "unlimited";
$SHOW_FAVICON = "on";

$TITLE = "My fancy Serverpage";
$TITLE_BLOCK_ONE = "General Information";
$TITLE_BLOCK_TWO = "Players";

$ping = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.minetools.eu/ping/' . $SERVER_IP . '/' . $SERVER_PORT . ''), true);
$query = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.minetools.eu/query/' . $SERVER_IP . '/' . $QUERY_PORT . ''), true);

if(empty($ping['error'])) { 
$version = $ping['version']['name'];
$online = $ping['players']['online'];
$max = $ping['players']['max'];
$motd = $ping['description'];
$favicon = $ping['favicon'];
}

if(empty($query['error'])) {
  $playerlist = $query['Playerlist'];
}

echo $SERVER_IP;

?>
```

I tried setting $SERVER_IP = "1"; and successfully got the alert "1" when clicking on my button, so the location is definitely correct. But the data: on somehow doesn't want to pass through, and I have no clue why. I have also tried using $_POST instead of $_REQUEST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data must be [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)d if your `dataType` is `json`.

```
die(json_encode($result));
```

Otherwise, use `text/html` or something more applicable. You'll likely find the PHP response in the error function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'checkinfo.php',
    data: { address: "37.187.139.123", port: "26618" },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function(data)
    {
    alert(data);
    },
    error: function(response) {
        console.log(error=response);
    }
});
```

You can access the variable `error` in the JS console (F12 tools)

[jQuery $.ajax docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

I use this way:
...`dataType: "json"
}).done(function(response){` ...

so, after "json" u shouldn't use comma (,) and you need to put address and port in quotes like `'address': variable, 'port': variable`

I hope I could help you